# Added metadeta tag in AndroidManifest.xml in React native but still get error of "API key not found"

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working in React native application where i want to include the google maps . I installed the package and added the metadata tag in AndroidManifest.xml the details and my api key but still get the error of api key not found .

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      >
  

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   **<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyAtPscRyUn1QcOU"/>**
     
    </application>
</manifest>
```

what should i do now to solve the issue.

i restart the application after doing the changes also .
i clear cache and rerun the project .Still getting the error.

Comment: Remove ** from starting and end of meta data tag